# Customize context menu in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, contextmenu

I want to add some predefined text in the context menu under the "Author Queries" tab with sub menu, like below:

```
Author Queries
  FM
     Some text 
     Another some text
  BM
     Some text 
     Another some text
```

I tried in `contextmenu.xml` but I failed to get the desired output. How do I add the customized context menu?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Please show your attempt and show the output it produced.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I have added in contextMenu.xml <Item FolderName="Author Queries" />. after that dont know to modify the sub entries

Answer (score 1):

Here is the patern of contextmenu:
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/src/contextMenu.xml

search for this file (contextMenu.xml) and edit it adding those menus that will be usefull.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)